# Magento 2. How to remove widget on just one Product

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, widgets

I have a widget that is shown on all Category page and on all Product page.
I want to hide that widget from one specific product pages. Can I do It with **Layout Update XML**, if So how ?

The widget is shown **before main columns**

Comment: you want to hide it on single product only ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal, Yes

Comment: which theme you are using ?

Comment: Custom theme based on Luma